# Check if a dependency is correctly added in gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I added this dependency to my build.gradle:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies { compile ('org.smali:dexlib2:2.1.1') }
```

And I'm sure that exists:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/smali/dexlib2/2.1.1/dexlib2-2.1.1.pom

I tried with:

```
gradle buildDependents
gradle buildNeeded
gradle build
```

everything complete successfully but the jar wasn't downloaded and I can't import the classes.

How can I check if I added the right dependency?

> gradle dependencies

Am I running the right command for download the dependencies?

> there isn't a command for download the dependencies, it's an automated task during build

---edit---

```
$ gradle dependencies
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.smali:dexlib2:2.1.1
     +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
     +--- org.smali:util:2.1.1
     |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
     |    +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
     |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
     \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
\--- org.smali:dexlib2:2.1.1
     +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
     +--- org.smali:util:2.1.1
     |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
     |    +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
     |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
     \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.smali:dexlib2:2.1.1
     +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
     +--- org.smali:util:2.1.1
     |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
     |    +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
     |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
     \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.smali:dexlib2:2.1.1
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- org.smali:util:2.1.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
|    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
\--- junit:junit:4.11
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.smali:dexlib2:2.1.1
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- org.smali:util:2.1.1
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
|    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
\--- junit:junit:4.11
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: Add the output of `gradle dependencies`

Comment: Updated, thanks for help

Comment: Well, it does look like you have everything... What IDE are you using? Have you tried to reload the project?

Comment: The dependency is copied correctly, it's not a gradle problem.

Comment: IT WORKS! I use IntellijIdea and the import autocompletion didn't found the classes. After restarting the IDE it asks for add the jar to the classpath then it works fine... thanks @fge, post the answer!

Comment: Meh, that's not worth an answer; but what version of IDEA is it? Prior to 14.x, gradle support was rather sketchy...

Comment: idea 2016.1.1  and gradle 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Look like everything is just fine and that the jar's are downloaded into gradle cache.

To see where the files are located locally, you can always resolve the configuration and display the file locations. E.g. like this

```
task showJarLocations {
    doLast {
        configurations.compile.resolve().each { file ->
            println file.canonicalPath
        }
    }
}
```